# BetterPickers without a support library

Tags: android, datepicker, android-support-library, timepicker, fragmentmanager

I am using https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers to use time- and date pickers for my app. However, my app does not need a support library and it seems like I need SupportFragmentManager when setting a FragmentManager to the Time- and DatePickerBuilder :/ Is there a way to avoid the Support library?

Comment: I would be so thankful, if someone knows how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is going to work for the long term, but i ran into this problem as well. I ended up just changing the references in the library source from the support fragments to using the app.fragment alternatives.

I've only done this with the DatePicker and Number picker, and have just started testing it, so I don't know if this will work for all of them, but so far so good.